# How to redirect image requests to another dir via .htaccess?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The pictures are in the folder by the first **2 characters** of the file name, for example the `stack_help_me.jpg` file will be in the `/mnt/images/st/stack_help_me.jpg` folder.

The task is to make it so that all requests for pictures of a **specific subfolder** (for example uploads) are redirected to the desired file. For example, `/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/stack_help_me.jpg` to `/mnt/images/st/stack_help_me.jpg`.

**How to do this purely in `.htaccess` and is it possible?**

It seems to be understandable in PHP (although probably with errors regarding the `.htaccess` rules). Here's what I've tried:

`.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /wp-content/uploads/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) navigator.php?&src=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

`navigator.php`

```
$real_img_path = '/mnt/images';
$full_path = $_GET['src']; // /wp- 
content/uploads/2018/12/toster_help_me.jpg
$only_fname = substr($full_path, strrpos($full_path, '/') + 1); // 
toster_help_me.jpg
$image = $real_img_path . '/' . substr($only_fname, 0, 2) . '/' . 
$only_fname; // /mnt/images/to/toster_help_me.jpg
fpassthru(fopen($image, 'rb'));
```

Comment: Yes, now I know that htaccess works only from root dir and using only htaccess its impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /wp-content/uploads/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ [NC]
> ```
>
> ...and using only htaccess its impossible.

Using only `.htaccess` *is* possible. However, the regex above won't match a request of the form `/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/stack_help_me.jpg` (as in your example).

You could do something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file, *before* any existing directives:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/\d{4}/\d\d/((..).*\.jpg)$ /mnt/images/$2/$1 [L]
```

This specifically matches URLs of the form `/wp-content/uploads/<year>/<month>/<filename>.jpg` where `<year>` is any 4-digit sequence and `<month>` is any 2 digit sequence. You can be as specific or general with the regex as required.

`$1` is a backreference to the first captured subpattern, eg. `stack_help_me.jpg`. And `$2` is a backreference to the 2nd captured subpattern (inside the first), namely the first two characters of the filename, eg `st`.

PHP is not required.

**UPDATE:** If `/mnt/images` is actually located on a different HDD (outside of the `DocumentRoot`) but on the same server then you will need to create an `Alias` in the server config to map `/mnt/images` into the local URL space. You will also need an an appropriate `<Directory>` container that allows access to this location. Even if you end up using PHP to help fetch the images you will still need to give PHP access.

To route the request to a PHP script you could modify the above directive like the following:

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/\d{4}/\d\d/(.+\.jpg)$ navigator.php?src=$1 [L]
```

The `src` URL param would then hold just the basename of the file being requested.

Comment: I've read htaccess documentation and it says redirection is possible only to another dirs/files which are inside doc root, means. And the only way I can use htaccess like this, is to add soft symlinks to /mnt/ dir inside docroot (wordpress) dir. Am I right?

Comment: Everything in your question suggests this is all within the same document root? Where is the `/mnt` directory? (Incidentally, "redirection" is possible from/to anywhere. However, what we are doing here is an "internal rewrite", not strictly a "redirection" - which implies an _external redirect_.)

Comment: On another hard drive. Site allocated on /home/user/www/domain/public_www/ , images allocated at /mnt/images/

Comment: Is that a different _host_? Do you have access to the server config? You can use an `Alias` if it's a hard drive mapped on the same server. You can configure a reverse proxy if it's hosted on a different server with a different _hostname_.

Comment: Same server, and I have access. Now I think which is better - use aliases or symlinks.  What would you suggest? And what about PHP according server loading, would it be much more slower than other ways? The reason why Im thinking about PHP - maybe I will add some more logic according user agents or IP's to requests and its easier to handle by PHP for me.

Comment: Using PHP will certainly be less efficient. But if the file is outside the document root then you would probably need to create an `Alias` anyway? An `Alias` in the vhost / server config would be my preference - this is then part of the server config (unlike a symlink), should you ever change servers. Some Apache directives are processed _before_ symlinks are processed by the OS.

Comment: Now I have another problem, maybe you know what I can do with permissions ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54119965/apache-403-when-making-alias-outside-documentroot